# Javascript - Uncaught ReferenceError - Code seems perfect?

Tags: javascript, defined

Here's how I'm calling my JS:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="FCChatControl" onClick="toggleChatControl('cwa#item.OwnerID#')"></a>
```

"#item.OwnerID#" is a variable from a loop containing an ID. So the element I want to change the CSS for should look like: "cwa123" or some other number for the id...

Here's my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function toggleChatControl(id){
        var wnd = document.getElementById(id);
        if (wnd.style.marginBottom == '-1px') {
            wnd.style.marginBottom = '-236px';              
        } else {
            wnd.style.marginBottom = '-1px';
        }
    }
});
```

I ain't got a clue, it gives me the "not defined" error...

Comment: Wow. A `javascript:void(0)`, I haven't seen one of those in the wild for ages :)

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and Vanilla JS code?

Answer (score 3):

Out of scope, remove the document ready wrapper

```
function toggleChatControl(id){
    var wnd = document.getElementById(id);
    if (wnd.style.marginBottom == '-1px') {
        wnd.style.marginBottom = '-236px';              
    } else {
        wnd.style.marginBottom = '-1px';
    }
}
```

Every function creates a new scope, the global scope is `window`, and that's the scope used for inline javascript.

Inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` the scope is changed (to `document`) so the function is out of scope for the inline handler.

An even better approach would be to use a proper event handler

```
$('.FCChatControl').on('click', function() {
    toggleChatControl('cwa#item.OwnerID#');
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it becomes much easier to notice if you rewrite the original as `var toggleChatControl = function(id){...};`.